# Writing non-ascii content from pymongo to file

Tags: python, mongodb, encoding, pymongo, bson

I have a system that stores network traffic into a Mongo DB and I now want to retrieve packets from a specific connection and subsequently dump all the data to a file on disk. In the concrete case, it is gziped data and therefore starts with `\x1f\x8b\x08\x00`

My code to retrieve the data looks as follows:

```
with codecs.open("filename", "wb", "utf-8") as fh:
    for packet in packets:
        fh.write(packet["data"])
```

When executing the code, I get an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Having worked with Python 2 a bit already, I realize that encoding is always tricky. I have tried a numbers of combinations with encoding and decoding but either Python fails with a similar message or the resulting file is corrupted (e.g. throwing a `.decode('latin-1')` on it produces the correct unicode string but when written to the file, rather then writing `\x1f\x8b\x08\x00` the result is `\x1f\xc2\x8b\x08\x00`).

Also, reading basically any question and the appropriate answers here did not really me out :-( Any suggestions? Decoding the gziped data in Python is not an option, because the data might be arbitrary binary blobs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using ISO-8859-1 as encoding does the trick...